# Python: read a text file (each line is of dictionary structure) to a dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am trying to read a file to dictionary, each line is already in a dictionary format:

input.txt:

```
{u'FirstName': u'John', u'Title': u'Mr', u'LastName': u'Doe'}
{u'FirstName': u'Mary', u'Title': u'Ms', u'LastName': u'Doe'}
```

I then tried to do the following:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        data = {}
        data = line
        print(data["Title"])
```

Bit I got error:

```
    <ipython-input-18-a5a5994a6c1d> in main()
         18             data = {}
         19             data = line
    ---> 20             print(data["Title"])
         21 
         22 

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

---

What did I miss and what's the proper way to read each line of input.txt to a dictionary? Thanks!

Comment: `data = {}` followed immediately by `data = line` - what did you think would happen?!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the method `literal_eval` from [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html?highlight=ast#ast.literal_eval) library, this way:

```
import ast
with open("input.txt", "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        data = ast.literal_eval(line)
        print(data["Title"])
        print type(data) #To Check data type
```

Now, on your original code:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        data = {} #You are creating a new dictionary every iteration of for loop
        data = line #Re-defining data, which becomes string
        print(data["Title"]) #Then here you try index the data (string) with  a string ...that's wrong, string indexes are intergers
```

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve the end result by `ast.literal_eval`.

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("input.txt", "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        your_dict = literal_eval(line)
        print(your_dict["Title"])
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code:

```
data = line
```

undoes `data`'s previous existence as a dictionary, and re-assigns it to be a string.  Strings are indexed only by integers, hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

In your for-loop you read **strings** from file. And you need to convert it to Python `dict`. You could use `ast.literal_eval` to convert formatted `str` to `dict`.

```
import ast
with open("input.txt", "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        data = ast.literal_eval(line)
        print(data["Title"])
```

Comment: What would happen if someone changed a line of the file to `__import__("subprocess").call(["rm", "-r", "~/"])`?

Comment: @IanAuld Nothing good. I know differ between eval and literal_eval. But from question I assume, that input file have specific format.

Comment: There is a limited number of situations in which `eval` is considered safe and blindly calling it on input from a file is not one of them. Using `literal_eval` is a much better call here.

Comment: @IanAuld Ok, I updated my answer. Thank you for comment.